# Recuperar um valor que vem de uma rquisição jquey para PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

estou aqui com uma dificuldade, eu estou a receber um valor que vem de uma requisição JQUERY para ser apresentado em um input de form, com o código:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="valor">
```

Com esta TAG eu consigo recuperar o valor que pretendo no HTML, o meu problema agora é como vou passar ele para uma variável PHP.

Eu já tentei utilizar este método, segue o código:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
```

De seguido no PHP eu tento recuperar ele desta forma, segue o código:

**PHP**

```
$varphp = "<script>document.write(valor)</script>";
```

Mas não consegui, o que posso fazer para corrigir o código? Pois preciso que o código que aparece na TAG input do form se converta para uma variavel PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Essa interação não existe(ou não deveria existir).

Neste contexto o js está rodando no browser e o PHP está no servidor.

O valor do *input* deve ser passado para uma página PHP via requisição.

Comment: Ele já é passado 1x por meio de um form, mas como quero abrir 2 janelas de modal quero recuperar os dados da 1 janela, logo este <input> já contem a variável javascript que pretendo, o meu problema agora é conseguir converter este valor para o PHP, eu sei que é um procedimento estranho de se fazer, mas o que estou a fazer é bem complexo, por isso tenho de atalhar de alguma forma, porque são muitas linhas de código que teria de mudar!

Comment: Você já tem o valor no seu JS? então faça outra requisição(talvez AJAX) para outro recurso PHP.

Comment: Primeiro passo é esquecer essa sua ideia.
Scripts PHP não sabem o que é JS.